# Does TeamCity Visual Studio Addin support VS 11?

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, add-in

Does the TeamCity Visual Studio Addin support VS 11? If it does not, is there any beta or evaluation edition of TeamCity Addin that supports VS 11? If this doesn't exist either unfortunately, when will the formal edition come out?

I asked this question on TeamCity's forum, but no one answered it. :( Hope anyone here knows the answer.

Thanks,
Nate

Comment: it should be compatible with VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

The TeamCity addin will not currently install to VS 11. When I tried to use the add-in with VS11, it said it was incompatible. As of now, I have not been able to modify the addin to work with VS11. I cannot find anything on their site saying when it will be supported, either. I don't think they have announced anything yet.